# "'Python int too large to convert to C long" al intentar hacer un Update en Mysql

Tags: mysql, python, overflow

estoy teniendo problemas en Python3 al hacer un Update o Select de un numero grande en mysql. Mi codigo

```py
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=constants.DB_HOST, database=constants.DB_DB, user=constants.DB_USER, password=constants.DB_PASS)
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)

cursor.execute("""UPDATE `otros` SET `value`=%s WHERE `variable`='since_id'""", (1256729810954575872,))
connection.commit()
```

**Error que responde Python:** *OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long*

Al hacer un select no tira error pero responde con un numero incorrecto (mucho mas chico)

```py
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=constants.DB_HOST, database=constants.DB_DB, user=constants.DB_USER, password=constants.DB_PASS)
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)

cursor.execute("""SELECT `value` FROM `otros` WHERE `variable` = 'since_id''""", ())
db_response = cursor.fetchall()
```

En este caso esperaria que la respuesta sea "1256729810954575872" sin embargo python printea "462897155"

Revisando en stackoverflow una respuesta fue "*You'll get that error once your numbers are greater than sys.maxsize*". Sin embargo si reviso mi sys.maxsize resulta que es mas grande el maxsize que los numeros que intento manipular

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer es un BUG de mysql.connector con las sentencias preparadas.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96588

```
Description:
When SELECTing BIGINT columns, data appears to be retrieved using a buffer of MYSQL_TYPE_LONG instead of MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG.   This causes data values to be truncated unexpectedly, as Python fully supports long integers.

This problem does not apply to pure mode -- it is only relevant to the new feature of the C extension.

How to repeat:
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(use_pure=False)
cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT 922337203685477580")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)

Expected:
[(922337203685477580,)]

Returned:
[(-858993460,)]
```

**Lo tuve que solucionar transformando los numeros en strings en las querys con la DB.**

En **SELECT**:

```py
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=constants.DB_HOST, database=constants.DB_DB, user=constants.DB_USER, password=constants.DB_PASS)
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)

cursor.execute("""SELECT CAST(`value` AS CHAR) FROM `otros` WHERE `variable` = 'since_id''""", ()) #El cast as char hace que responda el valor del registro como varchar
db_response = cursor.fetchall()
```

En **UPDATE**:

```py
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=constants.DB_HOST, database=constants.DB_DB, user=constants.DB_USER, password=constants.DB_PASS)
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)

cursor.execute("""UPDATE `otros` SET `value`=%s WHERE `variable`='since_id'""", ("1256729810954575872",)) #Notese que envio el numero como string
connection.commit()
```

Asi si hace el update sin errores y devuelve el numero correcto con el select